# App Crashes using Parse local datastore

Tags: ios, iphone, parse-platform

I developed an app using Parse local store as most of the time the people using it have no internet connection my actions are pretty basic i only save data and then send it to parse(when they have connection),   most of the time this works fine but sometimes when they are going to open the app it suddenly minimizes.

Testing the app i found that when this happens this error occurs:

[__NSCFDictionary fetchFromLocalDatastoreInBackground]: unrecognized selector sent to instance xxxxxxx.

My question is: Does anyone have ideas on how to resolve this issue?

UPDATE

```
PFObject *theObject = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"ERAV"];
[theObject saveEventually];

theObject[@"Piloto"] = facade.ThePilot;
theObject[@"Copiloto"] = facade.TheCopilot;

theObject[@"Fecha"] = facade.TheDate;
theObject[@"Origen"] = facade.TheOrigin;
theObject[@"Destino"] = facade.TheDestination;
theObject[@"Matricula"] = facade.TheLicence;
theObject[@"Hora"] = facade.TheTime;

//Questions

theObject[@"Pregunta1"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer1];
theObject[@"Pregunta2"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer2];
theObject[@"Pregunta3"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer3];
theObject[@"Pregunta4"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer4];
theObject[@"Pregunta5"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer5];
theObject[@"Pregunta6"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer6];
theObject[@"Pregunta7"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer7];
theObject[@"Pregunta8"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer8];
theObject[@"Pregunta9"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer9];
theObject[@"Pregunta10"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer10];
theObject[@"Pregunta11"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer11];
theObject[@"Pregunta12"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer12];
theObject[@"Pregunta13"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer13];
theObject[@"Pregunta14"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer14];
theObject[@"Pregunta15"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer15];
theObject[@"Pregunta16"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer16];
theObject[@"Pregunta17"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer17];
theObject[@"Pregunta18"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer18];
theObject[@"Pregunta19"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer19];
theObject[@"Pregunta20"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer20];
theObject[@"Pregunta21"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer21];
theObject[@"Pregunta22"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer22];
theObject[@"Pregunta23"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer23];
theObject[@"Pregunta24"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer24];
theObject[@"Pregunta25"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer25];
theObject[@"Pregunta26"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer26];
theObject[@"Pregunta27"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer27];
theObject[@"Pregunta28"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer28];
theObject[@"Pregunta29"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer29];
theObject[@"Pregunta30"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer30];
theObject[@"Pregunta31"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer31];
theObject[@"Pregunta32"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer32];
theObject[@"Pregunta33"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer33];
theObject[@"Pregunta34"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer34];
theObject[@"Pregunta35"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer35];
theObject[@"Pregunta36"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer36];
theObject[@"Pregunta37"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer37];
theObject[@"Pregunta38"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer38];
theObject[@"Pregunta39"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.answer39];


//Extras
theObject[@"ValorTotal"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",facade.total];
theObject[@"RiesgoTotal"] = [self getTotalRisk];
if (facade.internationalNA)
{
    theObject[@"VueloInternacional"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"NO"];
}
else
{
    theObject[@"VueloInternacional"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"SI"];
}

[theObject saveEventually];
```

im using this code to save several requests and then when internet comes to the ipad the request "saves".

Comment: Please add the details of your implementation. This will help spot errors and lets us see if it is something you did wrong or if Parse did something wrong

Comment: @BjörnKaiser i updated my implementation if you can take a look

Answer (score 0):

The error itself was originated because there where to many requests stored in datastore and the app crashed due to memory issues this lead this error.

On the other hand my solution is I encourage my users to save whatever they want without internet but ensure that the last save of the day is done with internet connection this apparently sends all of the stored data at once.